# Visual Studio 6 Custom Toolbar

Tags: vb6

I have a legacy VB6 app that I still need to support. I also have a new PC and I would like to copy my custom toolbar that I created on my old PC.  Does anybody know where Visual Studio 6 custom toolbars are persisted to?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are talking about an addin. Addins written in VB6 for VB6 use a reference to **Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 Extensibility**. You compile the application as an ActiveX EXE and as such it can be placed anywhere on the hard drive. You can look at **vbaddin.ini** for the *addin.***Connect** setting where addin will be the addin name. Unfortunately this is not the file name or path, but it should be close enough to help you search the the application.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where that is stored, but you could try running [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) from SysInternals, and see what VB6 writes to files and the registry when you change your custom toolbar. To be honest though, it'll probably be quicker to set the toolbar up by hand.

Comment: yes, that would be easier but there are two buttons that I have know idea how I added them anymore.

Comment: Maybe you could change your question to "Where do these VB6 IDE toolbar buttons come from?", then describe them?

Comment: Dan R - you could have a look at the Add-in manager to see whether you have custom add-ins loaded.